Creating Pattern with jQuery and Repeat into Canvas
I'm working on a pattern placement algorithm for SVGs on canvas and it will be a WordPress plugin. I can place the SVG on the canvas and calculate the width and height values, however, since SVGs have indentations and protrusions, it's wrong to only consider the bounding box because this method creates gaps between the patterns. I tried to place the next pattern correctly, taking into account the actual boundaries of the pattern and the area it occupies, but I couldn't get the desired result with that either. A fixed value doesn't solve the situation anyway, because I have patterns with very different indentations and protrusions.
This is the image I got with the code I wrote:

This is the image I am trying to achieve:

I've been stuck at this point of the project for a while and I can't find a solution anymore. Where am I going wrong? I think I need a completely different perspective because I can't get the result I want with area calculation, width and height calculations. Can anyone help me with this?
Here is my codes:
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    const mainCanvas = $('#cmc-canvas')[0];
    const mainCtx = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');
    const svgElements = $('.cmc-svg-item');

    if (svgElements.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    function loadAndDrawPattern() {
        const tempCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
        let loadedSVGs = 0;

        svgElements.each(function(index, imgElem) {
            const svgSrc = $(imgElem).attr('src');
            $.get(svgSrc, function(data) {
                const svgElement = $(data).find('svg')[0];
                if (svgElement) {
                    const svgData = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
                    const svgBlob = new Blob([svgData], { type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8' });
                    const url = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

                    const img = new Image();
                    img.onload = function() {
                        tempCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                        loadedSVGs++;
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

                        if (loadedSVGs === svgElements.length) {
                            calculateRealDimensions(tempCanvas);
                        }
                    };

                    img.onerror = function() {
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                    };

                    img.src = url;
                }
            }).fail(function() {});
        });
    }

    function calculateRealDimensions(tempCanvas) {
        const imageData = tempCanvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, tempCanvas.width, tempCanvas.height);
        let minX = tempCanvas.width, minY = tempCanvas.height;
        let maxX = 0, maxY = 0;

        for (let y = 0; y < imageData.height; y++) {
            for (let x = 0; x < imageData.width; x++) {
                const alpha = imageData.data[(y * imageData.width + x) * 4 + 3];
                if (alpha > 0) {
                    minX = Math.min(minX, x);
                    minY = Math.min(minY, y);
                    maxX = Math.max(maxX, x);
                    maxY = Math.max(maxY, y);
                }
            }
        }

        const realWidth = maxX - minX;
        const realHeight = maxY - minY;

        const patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        patternCanvas.width = realWidth;
        patternCanvas.height = realHeight;
        const patternCtx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');
        patternCtx.drawImage(tempCanvas, minX, minY, realWidth, realHeight, 0, 0, realWidth, realHeight);

        const patternArea = calculatePatternArea(patternCanvas);
        fillCanvasWithDynamicPlacement(patternCanvas, patternArea);
    }

    function calculatePatternArea(tempCanvas) {
        const ctx = tempCanvas.getContext('2d');
        const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, tempCanvas.width, tempCanvas.height);
        let pixelCount = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < imageData.data.length; i += 4) {
            const alpha = imageData.data[i + 3];
            if (alpha > 0) {
                pixelCount++;
            }
        }

        return pixelCount;
    }

    function fillCanvasWithDynamicPlacement(patternCanvas, patternArea) {
        const patternWidth = patternCanvas.width;
        const patternHeight = patternCanvas.height;
        const mainCanvasWidth = mainCanvas.width;
        const mainCanvasHeight = mainCanvas.height;
    
        let currentX = 0;
        let currentY = 0;
    
        while (currentY < mainCanvasHeight) {
            while (currentX < mainCanvasWidth) {
                mainCtx.drawImage(patternCanvas, currentX, currentY, patternWidth, patternHeight);
                currentX += patternWidth;
            }
            currentX = 0;
            currentY += patternHeight;
        }
    }

    loadAndDrawPattern();
});


The code that I simplified and works in JSFiddle:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const mainCanvas = document.getElementById('cmc-canvas');
    const mainCtx = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');
    const svgString = `
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 800">
<g>
    
        <rect x="264.67" y="155.14" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -64.6533 310.9802)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="264.67" y="376.87" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -221.4386 375.9228)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="264.67" y="598.6" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -378.224 440.8654)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="379.39" y="44.48" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 47.1975 359.6844)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="379.39" y="266.21" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -109.5878 424.627)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="379.39" y="487.94" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -266.3731 489.5696)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="493.72" y="155.05" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 2.501 472.9144)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="493.72" y="376.78" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -154.2844 537.857)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="493.72" y="598.51" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -311.0697 602.7996)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="149.91" y="44" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -19.6769 197.2807)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="149.91" y="265.73" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -176.4623 262.2233)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="149.91" y="487.46" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -333.2476 327.166)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="35.37" y="155.19" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -131.8461 148.8535)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="35.37" y="376.92" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -288.6314 213.7962)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="35.37" y="598.65" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -445.4168 278.7388)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="609.15" y="44.62" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 114.3931 522.1906)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="609.15" y="266.35" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -42.3922 587.1331)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
<g>
    
        <rect x="609.15" y="488.08" transform="matrix(0.7071 -0.7071 0.7071 0.7071 -199.1776 652.0757)" fill="#231F20" width="156.78" height="156.78"/>
</g>
    </svg>`;

    function loadSVGData(svgString, callback) {
        const svgBlob = new Blob([svgString], { type: 'image/svg+xml' });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);
        const img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            callback(img);
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        };
        img.onerror = function() {
            console.error('SVG yüklenemedi.');
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        };
        img.src = url;
    }

    function drawSVGOnCanvasRepeated() {
        loadSVGData(svgString, (img) => {
            const patternWidth = 100; // Desired width of each SVG pattern
            const patternHeight = 100; // Desired height of each SVG pattern

            let currentX = 0;
            let currentY = 0;

            while (currentY < mainCanvas.height) {
                while (currentX < mainCanvas.width) {
                    mainCtx.drawImage(img, currentX, currentY, patternWidth, patternHeight);
                    currentX += patternWidth;
                }
                currentX = 0;
                currentY += patternHeight;
            }
        });
    }

    drawSVGOnCanvasRepeated();
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<canvas id="cmc-canvas" width="1020" height="450" style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
</div>




Please create a minimal reproducible example

I don't know how to make it more minimal. The topic I want help with is complex and therefore I have a lot of code.

you need to create a running link of your current code on stackoverflow or on jsfiddle so that we are able to check your issue and rectify it. edit your quetion and click on code icon to create a running example: https://prnt.sc/oF2M0HkEDJ8L or use https://jsfiddle.net/

I know that you are creating this in canvas, but are you planning/expecting to make the tiles "interactive"/clickable etc.? Or should it just be a "decorative" pattern?

code snippet is added @Death-is-the-real-truth. and here is the JSFiddle Link: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/cgvm8y6n/

no @chrwahl will not be interactive, it will only create a decorative pattern.

@Tayfun  offset required to achieve, so try: currentX += patternWidth-13; and currentY += patternHeight-16;

@Death-is-the-real-truth A fixed value doesn't solve the situation anyway, because I have patterns with very different indentations and protrusions.

A repeating pattern goes from -Infinity to +Infinity. You can't have it start with transparency then repeat. You need to either repeat it yourself, or clip your area.

Actually, a repeat from -infinite to +infinite would work better for me, but I don't understand if it is a transparent start because I start repeating inside the canvas. @Kaiido

But then it's just the inner grid that remains. That's trivial to implement using createPattern(). Your pattern's source just becomes https://i.sstatic.net/ZLfdkMfm.png

@Death-is-the-real-truth FYI, a Stack Snippet is not required for an MRE/MCVE. If you can copy the code to your own environment and run it there, off-site, to reproduce the issue, then it counts as an MCVE. OP was lacking the SVG markup here, yes, but an MCVE/MRE need not be runnable on-site. Just to make sure there's no confusion.

@TylerH My own code is very complex and allows multiple SVGs to overlap and create a texture, which is then spread across the canvas. It's running on WP infrastructure, so when I tried to run the full code here, I couldn't get results and it didn't work properly. now I have to manually adjust the gridlines and margins in the backend for the mosaic.

@Tayfun I think you meant to reply to someone else.
